# d3js force node starting position

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to load every node to it's position and then start force that will move nodes away from each other so they don't overlap. Currently I have working but nodes are moved all over screen at force start and not staying at their initial position when force is started. Is there a way to set initial position and then start collision detection with force?

jsfidle example: http://jsfiddle.net/2eM8Z/

```
I tried setting cx and cy before defining force but that did not help
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to initialise the positions of the nodes in a force layout, you need to set the `x` and `y` attributes, as this is what the force layout uses -- not `cx` and `cy`. If you do that with your current code however, it won't work because the nodes will overlap initially which means that the repulsive forces are too strong. It works fine if you place them a small distance apart to start with.

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2eM8Z/1/).

Comment: By changing the collision-detection code, you can make it work even with the circles initially overlapping exactly; just check for zero values in the calculations and replace them with an arbitrary small but non-zero value: http://jsfiddle.net/2eM8Z/2/

Comment: Additionally you can set the inital node positions (described at https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7881887) and use D3's circle packing https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7882658 to give reasonable starting positions to avoid distracting jitter.