# Updating force-graph on D3. Graph duplicates instead of updating

Tags: d3.js

Could anyone please help me with the update pattern? For now this is what I get when I give my graph React component new data... the old one stays...
This is where I have my code https://github.com/danieltkach/react-d3-integration
I've been reading about it an I understand I have to do "stuff" in here... replace enter with join() ? And then do the 3 update functions inside? ...

```
// SVGs creation ---
        const linkSvg = svgRef.current
            .selectAll('path')
            .data(LINKS, d=>d.agentName)
            // .enter()
            .join(
                enter => enter.append('path')
                    .attr('stroke', d => !d.weight ? "gray" : linkStyles.onlineColor)
                    .attr('stroke-width', d => linkWeightScale(d.weight))
                    .attr('stroke-dasharray', d => {
                        if (!d.weight) return linkDashedScale(d.weight)
                    }),
                update => update,
                exit => exit.call(exit=>exit).remove()
            )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here on GraphGenerator.jsx:

```
    svgRef.current = d3.select('#viz')
        .attr('width', svgWidth)
        .attr('height', svgHeight)
        .append('g') // a new group is appended
```

You're appending a new `g` element each time. That new element has no data, so nothing is removed or updated in the join.  If you remove the `.append('g')` it should work.

EDIT:

Furthur down in your node creation you use:

```
    const circles = svgRef.current
        .selectAll()
        .data(NODES)
        .join("g");
```

You aren't selecting anything, so nothing can be updated. Use this there:

```
const circles = svgRef.current
            .selectAll('.node')
            .data(NODES)
            .join("g")
            .classed('node',true)
```

Comment: Close. The links get "updated", or old ones removed, but the nodes not, they stay, they duplicate. Thank you SmokeyShakers.

Comment: The part where I have the nodes, I tried to do it similarly to the links but the result is still either duplication or improper placement:  // Nodes ---
  const circles = svgRef.current
   .selectAll()
   .data(NODES)
   // .join("g");
   .join(
    enter=>{
     enter.append("circle")
     .attr("r", d => styles[d.type].size)
     .attr("fill", "#212322")
     .append("circle")
     .attr("r", d => styles[d.type].size * Math.random())
     .attr("fill", 'url(#gradient)')
     .attr("stroke-width", 1);
    },
    update=>update,
    exit => exit.call(exit=>exit).remove()
   )

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Same result. Nodes stay on.

Comment: I had to do .selectAll("g") instead of ".node" and it worked. Thank you SmokeyShakers.

Comment: Now my issue is that it springs when new data comes in instead of smoothly relocating the nodes and links: https://youtu.be/udKhOI3PnnY

Comment: So, the problem there is that you need to supply the initial coordinates (i.e. where the nodes are before you add a new one).

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: It's beyond the scope of the initial question.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765274/d3js-force-node-starting-position) is a better answer than i could provide anyway.